# Remove top indent of itemize inside a table

Tags: page-breaking, minipage, tabularx

I am trying to create a list inside a `tabularx` environment. If I use `itemize` directly, there's an ugly top space which I would like to remove. The solution I found was to use `minipage` around the `itemize` so I can control the top margin, but since `minipage` doesn't follow page break, that's not good.

How can I control the top indent of `itemize` within the cell of an array ?

Comment: the `minipage` are not affecting page breaking.

Comment: English is not my native language so my message is probably not clear, because that's not what I meant. What I meant is that `minipage` do not break at page break, which is problematic in my case, as visible in the MWE. So if I could get rid off minipages, I'd be very happy

Comment: Your English is fine. However the minipage are not stopping breaking as table cells never break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't break cells across pages; what you can do is splitting the itemize environment across rows.

That said, you don't need to use a minipage. With the `enumitem` package, I define a `tabitemize` environment that removes the vertical space at the beginning of the cell:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[tabitemize]{wide=0pt, label = \textemdash, topsep=0pt, before=\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2.5cm}p{1cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\textsf{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{3}{X}{Bar}\\\addlinespace
\textsf{\textbf{b}} & Bar\\
\textsf{\textbf{c}} & \textsf{\textbf{d}} & \textsf{\textbf{e}} & \textsf{\textbf{f}}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
  & 1 &
 \begin{tabitemize}
 \item a
 \item b
 \end{tabitemize}
  & I don’t need to use \texttt{minipage}with the \texttt{tabitemize} environment\\\addlinespace[5mm]
  & 2 &
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item a
 \item b
 \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}
  & And here is the result with \texttt{minipage}\\\addlinespace[5mm]
%
  & 3 &
  \begin{tabitemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \end{tabitemize}\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this technique is that if I write something above the `tabitemize`, it will be overlapped by the latter (in this example, `& 3 & this will be overlapped
  \begin{tabitemize} ...`. I am generating these data automatically, so if I could have a single environment that would work on all cases (because here I would switch to `itemize`, but that's because I'm a human), that would be perfect. If it's not possible, I'll just try to automate this.

Comment: That's precisely why I defined a special environment. For the case you mention, just use ordinary `itemize` (with the same options for coherence, except `before= …`).

Comment: I'm afarid there's not much to do: I don't know of a way for itemize to detect if there's some text in the cell before it  begins.